# How to Verify AWS Cognito User Authentication in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-cognito

I've successfully integrated AWS Cognito for user authentication in my web app and linked it to the front-end (Angular), and everything works perfectly. However, I also want to verify user authentication in the back-end (NodeJS). I understand that one approach is to send the authentication token with each request, but I'm unsure how to check and validate this token on the backend.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The JWT token is composed by 3 sections Base64 encoded, with the first two being JSON after decoded, making it easy to read and validate. The 3 sections are:

- the **header** which contains metadata about the token, such as the key id and the algorithm used to sign the token.
- the **body/payload** which contains the claims about the user, userpool and client (if applicable).
- the **signature** which is the result of applying the cryptographic algorithm to the header and payload to guarantee their integrity.

The last is the most crucial to validate, to make sure everything else has not be tampered. This should be done by retrieving the JSON Web Key (JWK), which is usually located at `(...)/.well-known/jwks.json` (for cognito it'd be `https://cognito-idp.<Region>.amazonaws.com/<userPoolId>/.well-known/jwks.json`), pick the correct key id and use one of the available JWT libraries to verify (eg. [AWS JWT Verify](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-jwt-verify#verifying-jwts-from-amazon-cognito)).

After integrity is confirmed, a few claims should be validated, such as:

- `exp` for expiration time, make sure it hasn't passed;
- `iss` to make sure it comes from cognito and the right userpool;
- `aud` for ID token and `client_id` for access token should match the Cognito Client ID;
- `token_use` should be `access` or `id` depending on desired token usage (making sure an ID token is not used as Access or vice-versa).

Libraries, such as the above mentioned, generally also validate these fields, and more.

You can find more detailed information in the [Cognito Developer Guide - Verifying a JSON Web Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html).